# Is it possible to automatically adjust the size of the title bar in WPF based on monitor DPI scaling?

Tags: wpf, dpi-aware

I'm trying to make the title bar of a WPF main window automatically adjust its size to the DPI scaling of the monitor that's showing the application.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything useful on the internet other than the official example application in [WPF-Samples/PerMonitorDPI](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/PerMonitorDPI) on GitHub.

The title bar doesn't change its size even in the given application sample.

How to reproduce:

1. Start the WPF application sample (see link above).
2. Drag the application window to a higher-scaled screen (200%).
3. Notice the small title bar of the application window. Everything else scales bigger but not the title bar.

Comment: Is it possible to set the height of your framework title bar element to Auto? Without more information or any code to go on, we're just going to be guessing.

Comment: Why don't you follow the official sample? [Turn on Windows level Per monitor DPI awareness in app.manifest](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/PerMonitorDPI#1turn-on-windows-level-per-monitor-dpi-awareness-in-appmanifest)